# Complexity of the mandelbrot set on rationals

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, time-complexity, space-complexity, fractals

(Also posted on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283309/complexity-of-the-mandelbrot-set-on-rationals)) Given two rationals $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, call $c = a + ib$, i.e., the complex number represented by these two rationals.

A point $c$ is contained within the Mandelbrot Set $M$ if the following procedure never halts:

$z = c$

$while (abs(z) <= 2)$

$\hspace{0.3in} z = z*z+c$

Normally we pick some $k$ (say, 50) and then if it doesn't halt after that many iterations we assume it is in the Mandelbrot set and stop looping. Is there a polynomial time algorithm for determining if a given $c$ does not break out of this loop after $k$ steps, in terms of the magnitude of $k$ and in terms of $n$ bits representing the numerator and $n$ bits representing the denominator of $a$ and $b$?

For reference, $abs(c) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $c*c = a^2 + 2abi +b^2i^2 = a^2 - b^2 + 2abi$ because $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283309/complexity-of-the-mandelbrot-set-on-rationals

Comment: This question (and answers) seem to address the issue: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035215/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-some-point-belongs-to-mandelbrot-set-is-this-an-ex

Comment: @EmilJeřábek sorry about that, this being closed then makes sense. However, it has been about 10 months since I posted it there and it still doesn't have a good answer besides a heuristic I found. Computational complexity being a more natural fit for this community anyway, could my question be opened again now?

Comment: I doubt you can get any better answer than on mathoverflow (i.e., there is likely no such algorithm, but this would be difficult to prove), but whatever. I can vote to reopen the question, but you need to include a link to the MO post in the question (comments are not guaranteed to stay).

Comment: The paper *[The Complexity of the Real Line is a Fractal](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=1%2C22&q=The+complexity+of+the+real+line+is+a+fractal)* is only tangentially related, but might nonetheless be interesting to those interested in the topic of the post.